# Silverlight Depedency Property Not Updating/Changing

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties

I am having trouble updating a dependency property in Silverlight.  I am setting a property and notifying it changed in my parent class.  The custom control listens to this property changing through a dependency property, but it never hits it (calls the change callback).  I have been playing around with it and the only time I can get it to hit is if I set a default value, but it never takes on the new value.  I am setting breakpoints and seeing the values changing, and even put a textblock with the NotificationModel.Type object to it and it changes fine.  Please help!

Main.xaml

```
  <views:NotificationView x:Name="NotificationView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Notification="{Binding Path=DataContext.Notification, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"></views:NotificationView>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 void part_NotificationChanged(object sender, NotificationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notification = new NotificationModel()
        {
            Notifications = e.Notification.Notifications,
            Type = e.Notification.Type
        };
    }

    private NotificationModel _notification;
    public NotificationModel  Notification
    {
        get
        {
            return _notification;
        }
        set
        {
            _notification = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Notification");
        }
    }
```

NotificationView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class NotificationView : UserControl
{
    public NotificationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    public NotificationModel Notification
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (NotificationModel)GetValue(NotificationProperty); 
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(NotificationProperty, value); 
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotificationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Notification", typeof(NotificationModel), typeof(NotificationView), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnNotificationChanged)));


    private static void OnNotificationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificationView view = d as NotificationView;

        if (view != null)
        {
            NotificationModel notification = e.NewValue as NotificationModel;

            if (notification != null)
            {
                switch (notification.Type)
                {
                    case NotificationType.Success:
                        view.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new SuccessView() { Message = notification.Notifications.FirstOrDefault() });
                        break;
                    case NotificationType.Error:
                        view.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new ErrorsView() { Errors = notification.Notifications });
                        break;
                    case NotificationType.Caution:
                        break;
                    default:
                        view.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see nothing wrong with the code you have posted so far.  There is an assumption that `OnPropertyChanged` is firing the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented by the containing class.

My attention would be on the `Binding` itself.  These usually fail silently, if the property path is not resolvable nothing usually happens.

Are you sure you need to reference the `LayoutRoot` by name?  Does the control not already sit inside `LayoutRoot` without other ancestor controls having their `DataContext` diverted elsewhere?  Why is two way binding needed, that seems highly odd?  Try simply:-

```
<views:NotificationView x:Name="NotificationView" Notification="{Binding Notification}" ... />
```

Comment: Trust me I have done that also, it is just left over code that I tried to use instead of the one you just mentioned, but works the same though.  Yes it must be somehow silently failing and I just can't pin point how or where.